# How can I change the log directory?

Tags: shopware6

By default, the logging directory in Shopware6 is var/log.

How can I change it to something different like /var/log/shopware6 without creating a symlink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [directory is a Symfony default](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-log-directory). You can change it by setting an environment variable `APP_LOG_DIR` with an absolute path to a writable directory e.g. in you `.env` file.